# Return a StringContent from async

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How do I return a `StringContent` from async? Do I still need to return it as a task? Below is the sample code that I am using:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrder(string url)
{
    xml = "<result><success> True </success><message></result>";

    responseMessage = await httpContent;
    return new  HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
    };    
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the code you posted?

Comment: I'm getting an error " await cannot be used with string content"

Comment: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: This line -> `responseMessage = await httpContent;` makes no sense. what is going on there? because you return a valid response right after it in the next line.

Comment: I posted the sample code, that i was testing. It was not supposed to be over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrder(string url)
    {
        string xml = "<result><success> True </success><message></result>";

        return await Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage()
                                                    {
                                                        Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
                                                    });

    }
```

if so your return xml is also invalid. To quote one of the many online xml validators "*The element type "message" must be terminated by the matching end-tag* "  (message)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not actually using `async/await` then the method would look like this.

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrder(string url) {
    xml = "<result><success> True </success><message></result>";

    var responseMessage = new  HttpResponseMessage() {
        Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
    }; 

    return Task.FromResult(responseMessage);   
}
```